# Premeture end of content length delimitted message body

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am using `TestNG` framework with java selenium web driver but getting the following error

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 56258; received: 53248 )
```

please help me with how to fix the issue.

I am  using firefox `20.0.1` and selenium jar files version `2.32.0`

Comment: Can you try an older version of firefox? Per selenium change logs, they support only till 20.0

Comment: If these tests were working fine previously using older version of firefox, try degrading the version of firefox.

Comment: same problem with older versions also